# Microsoft Office 2010 on four home computers

Tags: microsoft-office, license

The license says up to 3 computers, and right now I've just acquired a fourth computer that I need to use. How can I include this computer into my license without purchasing a whole new license? Is there a way to do this? Even if it requires paying for the additional computer to be included in the license (as in upgrading the license). This is for non-commercial use and just my personal computers (laptops and a desktop based on my what I'm doing).

Comment: @Steph - You don't;  You won't be able to activate the 4th installation.  Microsoft just came out with a reasonable alternative with Office 365 for a single computer

Comment: @PeterFitzgerald No I haven't, and to be honest I prefer not to. I want to stay within the license.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the suggestion, I might just do that. In fact since I'm on 2010 it might be worth upgrading all my computers to 365 which if I understand correct is pretty much 2013, or at least a lot closer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot but as suggested by Ramhound in the comments I might be better off just going with Office 365.

Comment: What exactly is `Windows 365`?

Comment: My apologies I meant Office 365